# Probability Density Function for Particle Time of Flight

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, physics

I haven't had a course or any formal training in statistics so I apologize in advance for any butchered explanation/terminology.

Consider a particle at the origin pointing in some direction. It rests in a uniform magnetic field and given a kick. See image:

[image]

Unless $\theta = 0,\pi$, it will take a finite amount of time to hit one of the two represented planes. The particle will travel in the familiar helix pattern and as such two angles are unnecessary. We consider $\theta'$, the angle from the plane normals. Then the time of flight is easily found from the transverse velocity,

$$ t = \frac{d}{v}\frac{1}{\cos\theta'} $$

$d$ and $v$ are constant (to simplify things). The only distribution going into this is the emission angle (isotropic). I understand this to be generated as $\theta' = \arccos(1 - 2q)$ with the uniform $q:[0, 1)$.

The question at this point, is what is the PDF for $t$? I.e. what's the probability of a particle reaching a plane within some window $[t_i, \, t_i+dt]$?

Side comment: If anyone's got any good stat book recommendations, that'd be awesome.

Comment: what is the distribution of initial velocities and angles? are the angles and velocities correlated? assuming d is constant here ...

Comment: you might assume that speed $|v|$ is lognormally distributed with logmean $\mu$ and log normal sigma $\sigma$ ... you might assume that angle is uniformly distributed as $U[0,2\pi ]$

Comment: @phdmba7of12 edited for clarification

Comment: There are general analytic methods in both 2 and 3 dimensions for getting the distribution of a function $g(Y)$ if $Y$ is a random variable of known distribution. [Maybe start here.](https://www.math.arizona.edu/~jwatkins/f-transform.pdf). Also, you can simulate many realizations of $Y,$ find $g(Y),$ make a histogram of $g(Y)$, find the kernel density estimate of its dist'n, or use its empirical cumulative distribution function. // For a clear & specific answer here, you will need to specify orig'l distn's in 2 or 3-D and constants. As it stands, it is unclear what your asking for.

Comment: @BruceET I'll check out the page you linked and I'll simply specify exactly the situation in the post. Hopefully that will make more of a question. I'll simply try to reverse-engineer the process following. Thanks!

Comment: I have a few questions: 1) If emission was indeed isotropic, there would be equal probability of emission for each angle. However, you provide a distribution for it (involving the arctan) that is definitely non-uniform. Can you please reconcile this contradiction 2) What is $w$ 3) Does the collision time really have such a simple expression? You need to find an intersection between a spiral an a plane, should it not, for example, depend on the magnitude of the magnetic field?

Comment: @AleksejsFomins 1) If $\theta$ and $\phi$ are generated uniformly then you get an uneven distribution spherically. This is simply a by product of the spherical coordinates. [Check here for further details](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html). 2) 'w/' means with. I'm saying that one can generate a proper $\theta$ distribution through the transformation of a typical [0, 1) uniform distribution found in most programming languages. 3) Magnetic fields don't impart a force parallel to their direction. As such, the particles' transverse velocity is constant.

Comment: @CaptainMorgan Thanks, that clarifies it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify $T = \frac{d}{v |\cos \theta'|}$ because walls are symmetric in both directions

$$\theta' = \cos^{-1}(1-2q)$$

So

$$T = \frac{d}{v |1 - 2q|}$$

To avoid annoying absolute values, assume $q' \sim U(0, 0.5)$, because the other half produces exactly the same result, so has the same impact on the time distribution. So

$$T = \frac{d}{v (1 - 2q')}$$

According to [Theorem 4.1](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter4/4_1_3_functions_continuous_var.php), given a monotonic relationship between $T$ and $q$, the PDF of a function of a random variable can be written as

$$
\rho(T)
= \rho(q') \bigl| \frac{dq'}{dT} \bigr|
= \rho(q') \bigl| -\frac{v}{2d}(1-2q')^2 \bigr|
$$

Finally, we must plug in explicit expression $q' = \frac{1}{2}\bigl (1 - \frac{d}{Tv} \bigr)$ to get

$$
\rho(T)
= \rho (q') \frac{d}{2vT^2}
= \frac{d}{vT^2}
$$

with the constraint that $q' \in [0, 0.5]$, which translates to the constraint $T > T_{\min} = \frac{d}{v}$. The same theorem prescribes that $\rho(T) = 0$ whenever the constraint is not met, which makes sense, because it is not possible to reach the target faster.